# NLP CNN with Embedding, predicting 5 values from Twitter text

Tags: twitter, nlp, conv-neural-network, sentiment-analysis, embedding

I have a bunch of twitter texts (around 70K) that are around 10K words. Some are less and some are more. I have created a Keras architecture to predict 5 values for each Twitter texts and I have trained on those 70K. However, the accuracy (which is defined as follows: a match of pred1 and pred2 happens when all respective 5 values are with no more than 10 difference) is 21% (21% of the test data comply to the mentioned condition). I am not sure that the architecture, the tokenizer and the parameters are appropriate for this problem, but I will provide the code and ask for help. I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out why the accuracy is so low. Here is the model:

```
class NeuralNetMulti(Regressor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'keras-sequential'
        self.model = Sequential()
        self.num_words = 35000
        self.tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=self.num_words, lower=True)
        # self.earlystopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="mae",
        #                                              mode="min", patience=5,
        #                                              restore_best_weights=True)

    def fit(self, X, y):
        print('Fitting into the neural net...')
        #n_inputs = X.shape[1]
        n_outputs = y.shape[1]
        self.tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)
        encoded_docs = self.tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
        max_length = max([len(s.split()) for s in X])
        self.max_length = max_length
        X_train = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=max_length, padding='post')
        vocab_size = len(self.tokenizer.word_index) + 1
        print(max_length)
        self.model.add(Embedding(self.num_words, 512, input_length=max_length))
        self.model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=8, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
        self.model.add(Conv1D(filters=16, kernel_size=4, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
        self.model.add(Conv1D(filters=8, kernel_size=4, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
        self.model.add(Flatten())
        self.model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
        self.model.add(Dense(n_outputs))
        self.model.summary()
        self.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', 'mae'])
        history = self.model.fit(X_train, y, verbose=1, epochs=5, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=16)
def predict(self, X):
    print('Predicting...')
    encoded_docs = self.tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
    X_test = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen=self.max_length, padding='post')
    predictions = self.model.predict(X_test, verbose=1)
    print('Predicted!')
    return predictions
```

X in this case is just an array of strings (the texts). They could be 1000 words, but most of them are around 10K words. `y` is array of arrays with 5 values that I mentioned. Each of them is between 0 and 100. This model achieves 21% accuracy, but previously I used a TfIdf + PCA and basic Dense network and I achieved 62% accuracy on the same data. I would appreciate anyone experience in this field to give a professional advice. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to try using pre-trained word embeddings instead of random embeddings since you are dealing with lots of text here. You can start with static embeddings like GloVe and then try out contextualized embeddings like BERT. Please refer to this Keras documentation to see how you can add pre-trained word vectors - [link](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/pretrained_word_embeddings/).